# Could not initialize class net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI on ec2

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, tesseract, tess4j

I have developed the java application for OCR with tess4j library, and it works well on my local machine(i'm using windows 10). And i have deployed it to `EC2` instance which runs `Readhat`, and once the `doOCR()` invoked it returns following error,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI
```